# Bootstrap navbar "flashing" on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, svg, size

I'm currently using a fixed top navbar for my website, but I have a little design problem.

When a page is loading on google chrome, my navbar's height is higher than expected for a very short time and then it's taking it's normal size.

I have a svg object on this navbar, and apparently this bug happens while the svg is loading but it only happens on google chrome, I have no problems with Opera, IE or Firefox.

Here are some screens of what is currently happening.

During the loading :

http://uppix.net/7vCKxC.jpg

After the loading :

:http://uppix.net/VwI9lT.jpg

Thank you all in advance !

edit : Here is some code of my header, I just kept the svg embed in it because if I put it off, the problem doesn't appear.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<!-- Start of the nav bar content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <embed onload="SVG()" id="exp" src="./img/xp_bar/xb_bar_final.svg" width="300" />               
  </div>
</div>
```

and the SVG() function :

```
function SVG()
{
var path=document.getElementById("exp")
      .getSVGDocument()
      .getElementById("linearGradient5228");
      path.setAttribute('x2',document.getElementById("expratio").value*491);
}
```

EDIT2 : Adding a height attribute to the embed prevented the navbar to "flash" but the SVG is still flashing only on Google Chrome during the loading.

Comment: That's done ! I edited my post

Comment: Have you tried specifying a `height` attribute in your `<embed>` element?

Comment: That did the trick ! But my svg image is still flashing during the loading. It's less disturbing now that the navbar doesn't change, but it's still flashing only on Google Chrome !